# XMLHttpRequest for Video Tag?

Tags: javascript, html, video, xmlhttprequest

Has anyone tried using binary data from an XHR request to be the content of a video file?

Comment: Doc for those who want it: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

In `Blob`-supporting browsers, you can do the following and use a generate, given `req` is a `new XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var some_video_element = ...;
req.onload = function () {
    var blob_uri = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
    some_video_element.appendChild(document.createElement("source"))
        .src = blob_uri;
};
req.responseType = "blob";
req.open(...);
req.send(null);
```

Refer to [this workaround](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=52486#c27) for Google Chrome until `responseType = "blob"` is implemented.

Comment: Any idea if iOS supports blobs? I'm having a hard time finding the answer via google.

Comment: Would I also need to overrideMimeType? Example: 
 req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');

Comment: I've attempted what you suggested but failed. Would you please take a look at my Q at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997839/xhr-to-load-video