# XHR to load video

Tags: javascript, html, video, xmlhttprequest

Without getting into the details of why I'm using XHR, can anyone tell me how to get the below to work doing so? My goal is to first load the video data and then place it into the video tag's source.

http://jsfiddle.net/u2vhG/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = function () {
        var blob_uri = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
        elem.appendChild(document.createElement("source"))
            .src = blob_uri;
    };
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.open('GET', 'http://www.latentmotion.com/player/h264/clips/16154_2832659676_170_180.mp4', false);
    req.send(null);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="myVideo" width="600" height="334" controls></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Refer to [this workaround](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=52486#c27) for Google Chrome until responseType = "blob" is implemented.

— [Me, responding to your same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996543/xmlhttprequest-for-video-tag/5996884#5996884)

If you read my whole answer and the link, you'd see Google Chrome doesn't actually support `responseType = "blob"` yet. I gave you a hypothetical implementation and linked you to a workaround using `responseType = "arraybuffer"`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer again. I read your note and link refering to the Chrome workaround, but expected that firefox would work without the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here,

1. `req.responseType = "blob";` should come *after* `req.open(...)`
2. You are doing a cross-site request, which might fail for security reasons.

You should also `URL.revokeObjectURL` once you set the url. Note that in Chrome they still have `webkitURL` rather than `URL`.